# Object of class Illuminate\View\Factory could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am new to laravel 
my delete button in view blog.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('blog.destroy', $blog->id)}}">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><span class = "fa fa-trash" ></span></button>
</form>
```

Delete function on blogController

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
         Blog::where('id',$id)->delete();
         return Redirect::to('blog')->with('success','Blog Deleted');
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the controller method that is returning that view?

Comment: Your pasted code looks fine. Please provide more detail about the error such as error line. The related method which returns the view also may help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this codes

blog.blade.php:

```
<a href="{{route('blog.destroy', [$blog->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class = "fa fa-trash" ></span></a>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/blog/destroy/{id}', 'blogController@destroy')->name('blog.destroy');
```